# My gnome-shell gtk theme is really ugly

Tags: 11.04, gnome, gtk

I have installed gnome shell on my Ubuntu 11.04. It gave me an error about

```
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-session_3.0.1-0ubuntu1~build1_all.deb: trying to overwrite '/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome.session', which is also in package gnome-session-common 2.32.1-0ubuntu20
```

After a while with `-f` and stuff I managed to get gnome shell to work but the gtk theme looks very ugly. So I want to update and install the standard gnome theme and it gives me this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gnome-shell: Depends: libcamel1.2-19 (< 2.33) but 2.32.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
             Depends: libffi5 (>= 3.0.4) but 3.0.9-3ubuntu1 is installed
             Depends: libnspr4 (>= 4.7.0~1.9b1) but 4.8.7-0ubuntu1 is installed
             Depends: libnss3 (>= 3.12.2~rc1) but 3.12.9+ckbi-1.82-0ubuntu2 is installed
             Depends: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.7.3) but 3.7.4-2ubuntu5 is installed
             Depends: libxfixes3 (>= 1:4.0.1) but 1:4.0.5-1ubuntu1 is installed
             Depends: gnome-themes-standard (>= 2.91) but it is not installed
```

What to do. I know it's really unstable and stuff but I have some bug with gnome 2 and gnome 3 behind all of this. At least, that's what I read out of it all. How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I'm getting: The following packages have unmet dependencies: gnome-shell : Depends: gnome-themes-standard (>= 2.91) but it is not installed
when i'm trying to do dist-upgrade, or trying to install anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

Please do not use the Gnome 3 PPA. It is an **EXPERIMENTAL**, alpha, developer preview and you will almost certainly have various problems.

Answer (score 0):

run Synaptic Package Manager and remove the package called "gnome-accessibility-themes" then install "gnome-themes-standard"

That worked for me. I think there is some conflicting dependency somewhere in those packages.